# Sending a xml file in response to form in java application

Tags: java, xml, http, httpclient

I have the following problem and I have to solve this in my Java application. Please suggest.

1. Send a GET request to a sample url
2. it gives a form as below

   FORM enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
     Select XML job file name to post
     INPUT type="file" name="jobxml" value=""
     
   /FORM
3. attach xml file to this form and submit
4. step 3 gives a response response.xml
5. I need to access this url (GET) to get my xml response and process in my java application.

Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: Can you post some code as in what you tried?

Comment: 1. You handle the GET request and respond with an HTML form with POST. Either store the GET URL in the form as `<input type="hidden" name="..." value="...">` or call the same URL in `<form action="..."`. 2. You handle the POST request with all info in the request.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do some scrapping, there are tools that help you achieve you goal more elegantly. Geb is such a tool see: http://www.gebish.org/